# Comparison of elements in matrices in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, matrix, comparison

I'm triying to do a comaparison between two matrices in ruby.
I have the data in files:
fichero.txt  contains:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1

fichero2.txt contains:
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0

This is my code

```rb
require matrix
    m1 = Matrix.build(7,4){|row,col|}
    m2 = Matrix.build(7,4){|row,col|}
    File.foreach("fichero2.txt") do |line|
    m1 =  line
    puts m1
    end

    File.foreach("fichero.txt") do |line2|
    m2 = line2
    puts m2

    end

    for i in (0..3)
        for j in (0..6) 
            if m2[i,j] ==  m1[i,j]
              print "V "
            end
        end
    end
```

It supose to print 14 times "V" because there are 14 equals elements. But this prints 10 time "v" and I don't understand why.
Can you tell me why is printing 10 times instead of 14?
Am I storing th data correctly?

Comment: `m1 = line` will forget whatever was in `m1` before, and replace it with the string containing the current `line`. In the end, it will only contain the last line of the file. `m[i, j]` when `m` is a string is a substring starting at `i`-th character, with length `j` — something very different from what you want. tl;dr: No, you're _not_ storing th data correctly.

Comment: What if you just have a counter and then read the files and compare each char of line and line2 and increment the counter every time the chars are equal, that way you'd end up with a counter value of the matched chars, i.e. 14 in this case. Then you could just print the v `counter.times { p 'v' }`

Comment: Also, this seems very similar to an existing post -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60066398/how-to-compare-the-elements-of-two-matrices-in-ruby, but with a better-posed question though.

Comment: Do you want to / have to use the `Matrix` class for this?

Answer (score 1):

See following piece of code for an example. Substitute filenames with your own.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# USAGE:
#   matrix.rb
#
# Description:
#   Demonstration how to compare two matrixes
#
# StackOverflow: 
#   Question 60068512
#
# Author:
#   Polar Bear      https://stackoverflow.com/users/12313309/polar-bear
#
# Date: Wed Feb 5 12:43:00 PST 2020
#
#

$debug = 0              # debug flag

matrix1 = 'file1.dat'
matrix2 = 'file2.dat'

def read_matrix(filename)
  matrix = []
  i = 0

  File.foreach(filename) { |line|
    matrix[i] = line.split
    i += 1
  }

  return matrix
end

def matrix_compare(m1,m2)
  matrix = []

  for i in (0..m1.size-1)
    matrix[i] = []
    for j in (0..m1[0].size-1)
      matrix[i][j] = m2[i][j] == m1[i][j] ? 'V' : ' '
    end
  end

  return matrix
end

def matrix_show(m)
  m.each do |row|
    row.each do |elem|
      printf "%c ",elem
    end
    puts
  end
end

m1 = read_matrix(matrix1)
m2 = read_matrix(matrix2)

m3 = matrix_compare(m1,m2)

puts '
+--------------+
| Matrix m3    |
+--------------+
'

matrix_show(m3)

exit 0
```

Output

```
+--------------+
| Matrix m3    |
+--------------+
V   V   V   V 
  V   V   V   
V   V   V   V 
  V   V   V
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for a code writing service.

Comment: @Stefan OP lucks experience in ruby programming and doesn't understand how to fill array with data read from file. A good example will put her on right track. Experience come with a time and good examples of some code demonstrating various approach to to solving various problems. A good example at times is better than hours search in a book.

Comment: @PolarBear Thank you so much. It helped me a lot. I needed help because I'm a beginner in Ruby.